# Finding vectors at right angles to heading of an entity

Tags: vector, xna, heading

I'm looking for a way to find the vectors at right angles to the game entity's heading. One to the left and one to the right.

I'm using XNA if this affects the answer in any way.

Edit: this is a 2D operation. I saw on another site that the clockwise vector is simply [-y, x] and the counter-clockwise [y, -x]. This seems to work out on paper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vector product (aka cross product)

Answer (score 1):

The vector cross product will give you another vector that is perpendicular to the two input vectors.

The dot product can be used to tell what the angle between 2 vectors is.

However the problem description you've given only specifies one input vector, the direction of the entity. Therefore the solution is all the vectors in the plane that the direction of the entity is normal to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into the [Vector3.Cross](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195708%28v=xnagamestudio.30%29.aspx) function, I know you're looking to do this for 2D vectors but it shouldn't matter, just set your z component of the Vector3 to 0.

You should also probably read up on [Cross Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and [Dot Products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_products) as they are both very relevant to graphics programming and even games programming in genrel, and will also help you beter understand how to solve many similar problems you'll encounter with your programming :)